# Opening apps from WebView links

Tags: android, ios, webview, href

With iOS and Android web views, setting href in a link to `tel:123-4567` dials the phone number, while `mailto:abc@defg` opens the email app. Is there a way to define my own href prefix, so that a link in a web view opens the app of my choice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this go through below links :-

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

By Using above link you can open another app from your app after setting URL identifier in Plist of another app which you want to open and then call that URL from your current app. And another useful link for URLSCHEMA:-

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: Thanks for your help! I haven't had time to try this yet, but I'll let you know what happens when I do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check  element in your Manifest to register a customized scheme of your application to the system. So you could be able to invoke the app with HTML hyperlinks.

For instance:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="anton" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <--Not positive if this one is needed
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

A simple example can be found at http://www.jayway.com/2009/09/24/the-browsable-category-revealed/, also you can start from the keywords and find a ton of references on the internet.

For iOS you can refer http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html for example.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I have time, and post my results later.